# Why was the hazing seen in the initial montage so much more playful than Rosa's?

Tags: ares

The Dutch horror series [Ares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares_(TV_series)) opens with a montage of an (unnamed?) young woman joining the secretive titular *Ares* student association.

One of the scenes shows her going through a hazing ritual where she has to crawl through a tunnel whose walls are made out of cloth. We can see bright (sun?)light shining through the cloth from the outside, and the whole thing appears as quite playful.

Toward the end of episode 1x01, the protagonist, Rosa, undergoes the same ritual. This time, however, it appears considerably darker (both visually and figuratively): There is no light visible from the outside, the people who are sent crawling through the tunnel have bags over their heads, and the entire process leading up to the scene makes it clear that from the characters' point of view, it must pretty much seem like an abduction.

**Is there anything in the show or in producers' commentary that explains the different treatment (or at least different depiction)?**

Comment: The unnamed young woman seems pretty pleased with the hazing. She's smiling even as they yell at her and push her around. By comparison, Rosa is upset by the process. Could the cinematography simply be reflecting their relative mental states?

Comment: @Valorum: Yes, that's what I was wondering about, as well (cf. "or at least different depiction"). Given that her subplot goes nowhere and just serves for setting the tone, I tend to doubt that interpretation, though; it just seems too random and not really in line with the rest of the season, where events are not shown from different people's perspective, either.

Comment: Maybe it was just a different time of the year?

Comment: @Valorum: In which time of the year do you cover your head with a bag that you cannot see through again? Is that a Dutch thing? :)

Comment: lol. I meant in re: the light outside, not the bags over their heads. A hazing at 5pm in winter would be much darker than 5pm in summer

Comment: @Valorum: Agreed, if it were only the light, that would be a reasonable explanation. I asked because of the entire setting of the event, though, which is much different beyond just the lights - like with the described bags, but also the behaviour of those involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-universe, it is hard to tell, but I think it is a combination of several factors. First, the seasons probably are different, as someone guessed in the comments. One indication is that they are wearing T-shirts outside, whereas in the later episodes everyone is very wrapped up, even *inside*. This most likely influenced the decision to hold the hazing outside, and thus the bright and sunny atmosphere. Obviously, once you are holding the hazing in public, chains and bags over people's heads are a no-no, and there is little point kidnapping people *without* bags over their heads.

Still, this does not entirely explain *why* they decided to hold the hazing outside. Perhaps it is tradition to alternate in order to balance two competing interests. Outdoor, mild hazings part of the time maintain the illusion of an innocent student society, whereas harsh hazings indoors maintain their traditions from the trans-Atlantic slave trade. Another possibility is that the president sets the policy for the type of hazing, and thus there was a change of president between the two events.

Further, I strongly suspect that they might have opted for the harsher version of the hazing partly in order to punish or intimidate their one reluctant and one outsider candidates. Think about the first part of the hazing: identify the person who does not belong in Ares. It seems tailor-made to bully Rosa, no? And perhaps, to a lesser extent a member who had shown disloyalty—Jacob. This idea is strengthened by the fact that the two were specifically singled out for criticism, whereas the person who admitted to have killed someone in a car accident got off with a "we do not judge." When one's traditions are threatened, from within or without, they tend to be affirmed with adherence to stricter, more traditional versions of ceremonies.

Out-of-universe, I think the reason for the differences is basically what was mentioned in the question. The woman shown at the beginning is happy-go-lucky and carefree, and presumably an insider to the society, and so this is illustrated with a happy-looking hazing scene. Rosa is more reserved and negative, and a relative outsider, and so her personality is paralleled with a frightening hazing ritual. In fact, most of the scenes in the beginning sequence have parallels in Rosa's experience in the first episode or two. The unknown novitiate interacting with her parents versus Rosa's interactions with her own parents, the former's comfort in her classroom versus the latter's boredom and friction with the teacher, and so forth.